# Get Power (Voltage/Watts) with python or bash

Tags: python, linux, bash

Is there any possibility to get the input power (like the Voltage or Watts) of an linux operating system in python or bash?

My system is running with an battery and i want to shut it down when the battery level gets too low to supply the system.

Comment: This is probably going to need some more specific information about the system in question. Is this an Intel/AMD/ARM Server? Do you have an actual model number or anything like that?

Comment: the info in something like `/proc/acpi/battery/` may help ...

Comment: For example a raspberry pi with an external Battery USV

Comment: Step 1: Use something like OpenUPS that uses a standard mechanism for power status retrieval. Step 2: Use the standard mechanism to retrieve power status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read from the files in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT*/`.

Here are two of the more interesting files:

- `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity` - shows the current capacity (e.g. 75%)
- `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status` - current status (e.g. FULL/Discharging/Charging)

The information is also aggregated in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent`

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Unknown
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=10800000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=12464000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=0
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=93960000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=95090000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=94830000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=99
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=45N1173
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=SANYO
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=31144
```